# Installing the development files libqgis-dev in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu, c++

I am trying to install development files which include the headers and the libraries for qgis in Ubuntu 12.04. I used Ubuntu software center, synaptic and the terminal and am still getting the same result.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libqgis-dev:

-Depends: libgeos-dev (>= 3.0.0) but 3.3.3-2~precise2 is to be installed

-Depends: libgsl0-dev but it is not going to be installed

-Depends: libqgis1.9.0 (= 1.9.0+git20120902+5a0d2f5~precise-ubuntugis1) but 1.9.0+git20120902+5a0d2f5~precise-ubuntugis1 is to be installed

-Depends: libqt4-dev (>= 4.4.0) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed

-Depends: python-qt4 (>= 4.1.0) but 4.9.1-2ubuntu1 is to be installed

-Depends: python-qt4-dev (>= 4.1.0) but it is not going to be installed

-Depends: qt4-designer (>= 4.4.0) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed

Can anyone help me with this installation?

Answer (score 1):

According to [UbuntuUpdates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/universe/base/libqgis-dev):

```
Package "libqgis-dev"


WARNING: the "libqgis-dev" package was deleted from this repository


Name:   libqgis-dev

Description:    
Quantum GIS - development files

Latest version: *DELETED*
Release:    precise (12.04)
Level:  base
Repository: universe
Head package:   qgis
Homepage:   http://qgis.org/
```

Maybe it's part of what's causing your problem? The package doesn't exist in the repository anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Ubuntu sources , maybe you could switch to the official QGIS repository for Ubuntu ? See Instructions [here](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#261-Release). I don't use Ubunut, but i assume that the libqgis development files are available there.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the [instructions on the Download page](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#26-Ubuntu) it should work:

> Nightly builds of the Master are available from following repository (i386 and amd64):

```
Precise:
deb     http://qgis.org/debian-nightly precise main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian-nightly precise main

To add the the qgis.org repository public key to your apt keyring, type:
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 997D3880
gpg --export --armor 997D3880 | sudo apt-key add -
```